# Derive a functional equation for the characteristic function of $G$ given weak convergence.

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

The following is a problem from  Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes by Resnick.

We're given iid $X_n$ such that there exist $a_n>0$ and $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - b_n}{a_n}\le x) \to G(x)$. We're then asked to derive a functional equation for the characteristic function of $G$.

I know that weak convergence implies convergence of characteristic function, but after writing the equations down, I don't even know where to start.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Usually a functional equation means something like, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$; an identity expressed mostly in terms of the function $f$ that allows you to deduce properties of $f$. Is it possible the author *doesn't* mean this, and that they rather mean: "find an explicit formula?" Have they mentioned "functional equation" anywhere else in the book? The reason I ask is, I'm pretty sure you get wildly different answers for different choices of distribution of $X$

Comment: (and I have an explicit formula)

Comment: Not very clear what do they mean (the authors) with functional equation for $G$. However, ew have that $$\widehat{G}(t)=\lim_nE\Big[\exp\big(\frac{\sum^n_{k=1}X_k-b_n}{a_n}it\big)\Big]=\lim_ne^{-\frac{itb_n}{a_n}}\left(\phi_X\Big(\frac{t}{a_n}\Big)\right)^n$$ where $\widehat{G}$ is the characteristic function of $G$ and $\phi_X$ is the characteristic function of the common distribution of the $X_n$'s

Comment: @FShrike functional equation was mentioned in the context that if $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for $x,y>0$ and $f$ measurable, $f(x) = x^{-\theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, in the process of proving Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem

Comment: Right. The formula mittens gave (the same as mine) is perhaps the best we can do. I doubt a functional identity can arise from this